# SQL Table to MDB (SQL 2005)

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL table that I want to export to a MDB file. I've read around here that says to use the import/export wizard.

There's one problem though: The server I'm working with has no access to Microsoft Access so I can't simply create a new MDB file.

Is there an alternative to the Import export wizard or perhaps a way to create an MDB file without having Microsoft Access?

Comment: If your local-computer has Microsoft-Access installed, you only need to be able to talk to the Sql-Server.  MS-Access on the actual sql-server is not required.

Comment: I'm operating the server through a remote desktop since I don't have SQL locally as of yet (my company is still requesting permissions for them to install and grant admin privileges for SQL.)

Comment: I would try creating the JET-database on your local machine.  Then file copying it to the Sql Server.  The 'drivers' might be there...even if Microsoft-Access (the program) is not.  "Jet-database" is actually the correct terminology, even though few people use it.

Comment: Do I do it from the remote desktop OS or the local workstation?

Comment: You create the jet-database locally.  Then you remote into the sql-server.  You copy the .mdb to the machine hosting sql-server.  then try the export.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "doesn't have access to Microsoft Access", you mean the drivers are not installed?  Can you install them?

Alternately, you could export to another format (csv, for example) and import into Access.  Or you could create a linked table from within Access.

Comment: No, I cannot install them. When I say I don't have access to Microsoft Access, I mean I do not have a license to use them on the server.